# Rotation of UIImageView does not conserve center

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, rotation

Just setting a rotation transform to an `UIImageView` does not keep the center still. The image translate around de center, I'm puzzled. Any idea?

```
  CGAffineTransform
  transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
  transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, self.filter.angle);
  self.sourceImageView.transform = transform;
```

Note: the angle is coupled to a `UISlider` so that the user changes its value from **-90 to 90**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that setting the transformation to the layer fixes the issue.

```
self.sourceImageView.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(CATransform3DMakeScale(scale, scale, 1.), angle, 0, 0, -1);
```